# Removing lines from a file that don't match the begining of the line in second file

Tags: text-files, lines

I need to match two files with different values corresponding to the same individual. Both files are in .txt format, with columns separated by space. First column in both files contains ID numbers unique for each individual, but some individuals are missing in second file so they have to be deleted from the first one. 
First file looks like this:

```
1 value1 value2 value3...  
3 value1 value2 value3...  
10 value1 value2 value3...  
11 value1 value2 value3...
```

and the second one like this:

```
1 valuex valuey valuez...  
10 valuex valuey valuez...  
11 valuex valuey valuez...
```

I would need to delete line starting with ID 3 (second line) from the first file because this individual does not exist in the second file (values value1, value2 and value3 are not the same as valuex, valuey and valuez). 
My OS is ubuntu.

Comment: Well, using the backspace key on your keyboard generally works. You may have to press it more than once. Otherwise, please let us know how you're trying to accomplish this? Bash, Java, Python, C#/Mono? As of right now, your question is too broad and you need to let us know how you want to accomplish it.

Comment: :) I see your point, but, unfortunately, backspace would be a little bit impractical, as there are ~ 1000 lines and each line is several hundred thousand characters long. Bash would be great, or Perl.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution, but not a very elegant one. First, I cut first columns containing IDs from both files using:
cut -d " " -f 1 input file > output file

Then I used grep to print non-matching IDs from those files:
grep -v -w -f file2 file1 > ID_list

I anchored ^ at the beginning of each line of the file with list of non-matching IDs (suggestion of a helpful colleague). And, finally, I used:
grep -v -w -f ID_list file1 > new file1

to produce matched file. Not pretty, and I'm sure it could have been done in a much simpler way. But it works. Just wanted to post it in a far-fetched case that it helps somebody in future.